# Regular validation expression for mobile number

Tags: asp.net, regex

How to perform regular validation expression for pakistan mobile numbers?
Pakistan mobile number examples: 03339961128,03456831234,03215769989,03139981234

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1"
                                runat="server" 
                                ValidationExpression="" 
                                ControlToValidate="textboxph" 
                                ErrorMessage="Enter Valid Number!">  
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

what should I write in validation expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Validating phone numbers using regular expressions isn't usually the ideal method, and does tie your application down to a specific format.  It's easier to use a library for validating phone numbers, such as [libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/).  This contains server-side, and Javascript functions for validating, formatting and obtaining information on an entered phone number.  There are a number of advantages of using such a library:

- It will ignore any formatting (e.g. spaces, brackets, hyphens) that people often enter
- It will be able to format the number into the preferred display format for your country
- It will be able to tell you information about the type of number being entered

However, if you want a simple expression, using the examples you've got there I would go with `^03\d{9}$` (assuming Pakistan mobile numbers start 03 and have 11 digits).

Answer (score 0):

You can also validate mobile number through simple if-else check in this you can also validate whether user has entered correct Network code of Mobilink,Ufone,Telenor,Warid etc. In this function only 11 digit or 13 digits are acceptable like
e.g

**03463988574 (VALID)
+923332214561 (VALID)**

**08953055215  (Invalid)
+927415822875 (Invalid)**

You can also change its functionality according to your requirement of (PK) mobile number

```
 public static bool CheckMobileNumberFormat(string cellnumber)
        {
            bool ValidateNumber = false;
            IEnumerable<string> codes = new List<string> { "331", "332","333", "334","335", "336","337", "338",  //Ufone
                                                                   "300", "301","302", "303","304", "305","306", "307",  //Mobilink
                                                                   "321", "322","323", "324","325", "326","327", "328",  //Warid   
                                                                   "341", "342","343", "344","348","345", "346","347", "347","348"}; //Telenor

            if (cellnumber.Length == 11)
            {
                if (cellnumber[0] == '0')
                {
                    //string originalnumber=cellnumber;
                    string checkcode = cellnumber.Substring(1, 3);

                    bool match = codes.Contains(checkcode);
                    if (match == true)
                    {
                        ValidateNumber = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ValidateNumber = false;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    ValidateNumber = false;
                }
            }

            else if(cellnumber.Length ==13)
            {
                if (cellnumber[0] == '+' && cellnumber[1]=='9' && cellnumber[2]=='2')
                {
                    string originalnumber = cellnumber;
                    string checkcode = cellnumber.Substring(3, 3);

                    bool match = codes.Contains(checkcode);
                    if (match == true)
                    {
                        ValidateNumber = true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ValidateNumber = false;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    ValidateNumber = false;
                }

            }
            return ValidateNumber;
        }
```

//*** On button click****

```
string input = textBox1.Text;
            bool result = CheckMobileNumberFormat(input);
            if (result == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Valid #");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("InValid #");
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this validator expression for validation of all pakistani mobile numbers 
^((+92)|(0092))-{0,1}\d{3}-{0,1}\d{7}$|^\d{11}$|^\d{4}-\d{7}$